# MySQL group by most recent value

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
table prices
col id
col price
col currency_id
col timestamp (unix)
```

I would like to group the currencies by their ID and only show the most recent record based off the timestamp.

I have the following query which groups correctly but does not get the most recent records, always seems to get the first rows in the table rather than the last.

```
SELECT 
id,
price,
currency_id,
timestamp
FROM prices
GROUP BY currency_id
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

I did get lazy and attempt this which gets the last 6 records but the order isn't always the same and means I have to modify the query each time I add a new currency (currently 6).

```
SELECT 
id,
price,
currency_id,
timestamp
FROM prices
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
LIMIT 6
```

It has been a few years since I have done any MySQL and feel like this is the most simplest thing to do lol :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a sqlfiddle to test http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2a4e63/3

Start with this:

```
SELECT currency_id, 
       Max(timestamp) 
FROM   prices 
GROUP  BY currency_id
```

Then integrate that to main query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   prices 
WHERE  ( currency_id, timestamp ) IN (SELECT currency_id, 
                                             Max(timestamp) 
                                      FROM   prices 
                                      GROUP  BY currency_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I knew I was going at it the wrong way.. subquery slipped my mind completely. :)

Comment: Thanks. it's full-filled my purpose :)